# Akka ZeroMQExtension create multiple connection with one zeromq socket

Tags: java, akka, zeromq

Is it possible to create socket with multiple outgoing (ingoing) connections using ZeroMQExtensions?

More about multiple connections [in ZeroMQ guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Plugging-Sockets-Into-the-Topology).

**upd:**
I can't see equavalent sample with ZeroMQExtensions. In 0MQExtensions documnetation i found:

```
newPubSocket(socketParameters: Array[SocketOption]): ActorRef
```

*Java API factory method to create the actor representing the ZeroMQ Publisher socket. You can pass in as many configuration options as you want and the order of the configuration options doesn't matter They are matched on type and **the first one** found wins.*

PS: I don't known scala and just started reading akka documentation to understand I need Akka or not.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Please see update for understanding my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution (it was not intuitive but works):

```
    ActorRef subSocket = ZeroMQExtension.get(getContext().system())
            .newSubSocket(null, new Listener(getSelf()), new Subscribe("health"));

    @Override
    public void preStart() {
        super.preStart();

        subSocket.tell(new Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:1237"));
        subSocket.tell(new Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:1238"));
    }
```

Comment: Looks fairly intuitive to me (send the Connect messages with the destinations you want to connect to)

Comment: Thanks Viktor, nice framework. It was not intuitive for newbie in actors

Comment: Nothing is intuitive when you are a newbie :-) That's why learning is so rewarding!

Comment: You  right. But some little example with this technics in official guide can save time for newbies.